# CORS works on localhost but not on Production Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have enabled Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) for my REST APIs (developed using ASP.NET Web API technology) by installing the necessary nuget package and calling `config.EnableCors()` in my web api configuration class.

This singular change seems to have worked when I tried making a cross site call to the application running on my localhost from another ordinary html site on the localhost as well which was failing previously due to the single origin restriction.

Now having deployed this update to the production test environment, it seems not to be working. Almost pulling out all my hairs here looking for a solution. Maybe someone can help me identify something I have missed.

Comment: When you said this - `I tried making a cross site call to the application running on my localhost from another ordinary html site on the localhost as well `, that does not mean you have tested `CORS`.

Comment: @Arindam Nayak, I have an application running at http://example.com and from there I make an ajax POST call to url http://example2.net , that is what I meant.

Comment: @OswaldUmeh the problem still persists? if no please close the question by adding your answer and mark it as the solution. Else update your question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tagged your controllers with the `EnableCors` attribute?

e.g. from [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors)

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods not shown...
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't necessary since I have enabled it globally in the webapiconfig class using the `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"))` call.

Comment: okay, but you didn't state that - so it may help to update your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

Use this tool to investigate:

**https://www.test-cors.org**

*`https://www.test-cors.org/#?client_method=GET&client_credentials=true&client_headers=X-Api-Version%3A%202.0&server_url=http%3A%2F%2Falfa.jobit.io&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=true&server_methods=POST%2C%20GET%2C%20OPTIONS&server_headers=X-Api-Version&server_tabs=local`*

No solution yet !

Options are sent but no actual request. Here is how it looks like in Wireshark:

[image]

I spent more than 50 hours learning about CROSS. Until I realizad localhost behave differently.

**Preflight** is used once I add **custom headers** (in this case api-version).
On both localhost and production, prelight returns successful. I am still investigating and I will complete this answer when solved.

Here are my headers for successfull CROSS with the server running on localhost:

```
############ Request Headers (OPTIONS) ############

=== Request Details ===

Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://alfa.example.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.20 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: api-version
Accept: */*

############ Response Headers (Get) ############

=== Request Details ===

Connetion: Close
Date: Mon, 29 Oct 2018 19:50:40 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: identity
Content-Encoding: identity
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: api-version, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, User-Agent, Host, Connection, Authorization, timezone, X-CSRF-Token, Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept, Content-Type, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://alfa.example.io
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:0bdcbef4-4877-4790-bf3a-93aa6498f4df

############ Request Headers (GET) ############

=== Request Details ===

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://alfa.example.io
api-version: 2.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.20 Safari/537.36

############ Request Finished (Options) ############

=== Request ===

Method: GET
URL:    http://localhost:5000/contacts/register/23

=== XHR Headers ===

Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://alfa.example.io
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Host: localhost:5000
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.20 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Referer: http://alfa.example.io/?debug=&invitation=CB89EDA9-C305-464E-99A9-8AA861F44A6F
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Headers: api-version

############ Response Headers (Get) ############

=== Request Details ===

Date: Mon, 29 Oct 2018 19:50:40 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expires: -1
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: api-version, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, User-Agent, Host, Connection, Authorization, timezone, X-CSRF-Token, Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept, Content-Type, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://alfa.example.io
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:0bdcbef4-4877-4790-bf3a-93aa6498f4df
Api-Supported-Version: 2.0

############ Request Finished (GET) ############

=== Request ===

Method: GET
URL:    http://localhost:5000/contacts/register/23

=== XHR Headers ===

Pragma: no-cache
Origin: http://alfa.example.io
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Host: localhost:5000
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
api-version: 2.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.20 Safari/537.36
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Referer: http://alfa.example.io/?debug=&invitation=CB89EDA9-C305-464E-99A9-8AA861F44A6F
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.2021313723.1538951960; __test=1; _gid=GA1.1.1427728347.1540763978
Connection: keep-alive
```